# Banner image not shown in angular page

Tags: css, angular

I am still learning about angular so I might not have the best design, but anyways I get confused not being so sure where my css should be. I have src/index.html, styles.css and src/app/app.component.html, app.component.html. I am trying to customize home.component.html, no home.component.css has been implemented. On .parallax-container I am trying to show an image, but not showing as a background image.

[image]

**src/styles.css**

```
div.sm-jumbotron {
    padding: 2rem;
    background-color: #38547b;
    color: #ffffff;    
}

button.btn-submit {
    background-color: #38547b;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
}

button.btn-submit:focus, button.btn-submit:hover {
    background-color: #38547b;
}

input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty {
    border-bottom-color: #e91e63 !important;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #e91e63 !important;
}



nav ul a,
nav .brand-logo {
  color: #444;
}

p {
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.sidenav-trigger {
  color: #26a69a;
}

.parallax-container {
  min-height: 380px;
  line-height: 0;
  height: auto;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
  .parallax-container .section {
    width: 100%;
  }

@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
  .parallax-container .section {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
  }
  #index-banner .section {
    top: 10%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 600px) {
  #index-banner .section {
    top: 0;
  }
}

.icon-block {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.icon-block .material-icons {
  font-size: inherit;
}

footer.page-footer {
  margin: 0;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container" [style.margin-top.px]="navbarTopMargin">
  <app-nav (navHeight)="onNavHeight($event)"></app-nav>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div class="my-custom-container" [style.margin-top.px]="routerOutput">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div id="index-banner" class="parallax-container">
  <div class="section no-pad-bot">
    <div class="container">
      <br><br>
      <h1 class="header center teal-text text-lighten-2">Join Us</h1>
      <div class="row center">
        <h3 class="header col s12 light">We sell and deliver products to customers that will improve health.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="row center">
        <a href="http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html" id="download-button" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light teal lighten-1">Get Started</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!--Show this image-->
  <div class="parallax"><img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/architecture.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m4">
      <div class="icon-block">
        <h2 class="center brown-text"><i class="material-icons">flash_on</i></h2>
      <h3 class="center">Fast delivery</h3>
      <p class="light">
      We are the fastest delivery service in America.
      </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s12 m4">
      <div class="icon-block">
        <h2 class="center brown-text"><i class="material-icons">group</i></h2>
      <h3 class="center">Top quality</h3>
      <p class="light">
        We make sure the quality is great.
      </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col s12 m4">
      <div class="icon-block">
        <h2 class="center brown-text"><i class="material-icons">location_city</i></h2>
      <h3 class="center">Trusted company</h3>
      <p class="light">
        This company has received 98% satisfaction.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the code for image?

Comment: home component `<!--Show this image-->
  <div class="parallax"><img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/architecture.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>`

Comment: can you create stackblitz?

Comment: ok is very hard me to put on stackblitz, i just have github, https://github.com/alextech1/UserWebAPI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this css in your `style.css`:

```
.parallax-container .parallax{
    position: static;
}
.parallax-container .parallax img{
    position: static;
    transform: none;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: works just fine. I am still exploring new things, not too much aware about transition effects.

Comment: Well I guess it kind of works, in half window view, you can see the text on the image, but in full screen the text is above the image